# Calculate shortest paths for each output area in catchment through road network to a single point (i.e. store)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, distance, network

The title sums it up pretty much. I'm looking to derive trip distributions to a single store using population data and distance within a prescribed distance catchment. I have calculated the catchment area (polygon) using v.net.iso in GRASS and have clipped weighted population centroids that fall with the catchment accordingly. I therefore know the total population within the catchment, alongside the population of each OA centroid.

The ideal output would be: 
OA Geocode (column 1); Distance to Store (column 2); OA population (column 3)

I could achieve the above using the 'distance to nearest hub'geo-algorythm in QGIS, however, it uses straight line distance which is not ideal.

I have tried to perform the following in GRASS using the v.distance function, however, i am unable to output results by OA (node), only by the road network (arc), which is not what i need.

As well as the above, my main goal is to be able to find a way of identifying whether certain paths utilise certain roads to access the store. This will give me my trip distribution for my study network (i.e. to model individual junctions).

The following would be ideal:

OA Geo Code (column 1); Distance to Store; Road Link ID (specific road link) 0 or 1 (1 if used); Road link ID ""; Road Link ID ""; Road Link ID ""...; OA Population.

The above would be a very simplistic gravity model. I can do those separately, the identification of link would be by hand a though and would be very laborious.